# VB.Net Com Port reading

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project in which I have to make a GUI to connect with a controller via COM Port and retrieve the incoming data on the GUI. My controller accepts asynchronous commands in which the controller answers right away and synchronous commands in which they need some time until the answer arrives. I have created the GUI in Visual Studio VB.net.

My problem is when I send a mix of commands (synchronous and asynchronous) in a loop I cant read the answer of the 1st loop because i suppose it hasn't arrived yet  and continues to the next loop.
My commands endet with a semicolon character (`;`) at the end and so is also the answer of each command with a semicolon at the end.
As example i send `?TR;` and i am get the answer `TR=1;`

I thought a good way to watch if the whole answer of the send packet with commands is completed is to create a function that adds the received semicolons each time the `Port_DataReceive` method fires.

Here is my code of the `Data_received` method in which I am counting the received semicolons when arrives

```
Private instring As String = ""

Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)


    While CType(sender, SerialPort).BytesToRead > 0
        instring += CType(sender, SerialPort).ReadExisting
        ' MessageBox.Show(instring)
    End While
    Dim instrings() As String = instring.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    instring = instring.Substring(instring.LastIndexOf(";") + 1).Trim

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < (instrings.Length - 1))
        Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                              Try
                                  Try
                                      CommDataTable.Rows(SemicolonIn)(1) = (instrings(i) + ";")

                                  Catch ex As System.Exception
                                      inError = (inError + 1)
                                  End Try
                              Catch ex As Exception

                              End Try
                          End Sub)
        i = (i + 1)
        SemicolonIn = SemicolonIn + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

And here is my problem when i click a button event to send the loop of commands and check if the whole message was received

```
 Private Sub btnSendFile_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    'loop 
    For i = 0 To 5
        Port.Write("TGS;PW0;")       'TGS is asychronous and need some time till the ansew arrives
        ' i am sending 2 semicolons
        'wait until the controller answers with the 2 semicolons   -- here is my problem
        MessageBox.Show("The complete message" + (i.ToString) + "was received!")
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I cleaned this up. In the future, pasting your code in and clicking the code format button `{}` will do that for you.